# Is there an R function to create unique column values for unique row values

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am trying to create a new column "Dose". The values of dose are dependant on the values of the columns "Time" and "ID". For all values of Time which are a multiple of 168, there should be value for Dose. The value of Dose is further dependent on Value of "ID"

I am trying to use If-else statements 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOgJJ.png)

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be helpful. If you're assigning `Dose` based on whether or not `Time` is a multiple of `168` then you could do something like: `ifelse(data$Time %% 168 == 0, 1, 0)`

Comment: HI Matt the expected out put is as an image , it should be as follows TIME ID DOSE
0 1 1
168 1 1
336 1 1
341 1 NA
503 1 NA
504 1 1
673 1 NA
839 1 NA
840 1 1
0 2 NA
24 2 NA
48 2 NA
168 2 5
336 2 5
341 2 NA
503 2 NA
504 2 5
673 2 NA
839 2 NA
840 2 5
0 3 10
24 3 NA
48 3 NA
168 3 10
336 3 10
341 3 NA
503 3 NA
504 3 10
673 3 NA
839 3 NA
840 3 10

Comment: Also, how to further nest it based on ID, we need it to be a factor of 168 and specific for ID

Comment: In your expected output, `Dose` ranges from 1, 5, and 10. What is that logic based on, aside from being a multiple of 168?

Comment: The animal was dosed every week and the IDs are for different animals - 1,5,10 are the doses...based on your suggestion - i tried teh following - dose5<-ifelse(!DOSE$TIME%%168,ifelse(DOSE$ID==1,1,
                                     ifelse(DOSE$ID==2,5,
                                            ifelse(DOSE$ID==3,10,"."))),".")

Comment: for some reason - it works only if i use !DOSE$TIME%%168 .. why would that be?

Comment: Just the ordering of your statement, if you place the `"."` after your first `ifelse` statement, then you wouldn't need the `!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you.

sample data:

```
time <- c(0,168, 336, 341,503,504,673,839,840,0,24,48,168, 0, 24, 48, 168, 336)
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
data <- data.frame(time, ID)
```

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% mutate(dose = ifelse(data$time %% 168, "NA",
ifelse(data$ID == 1, 1, 
ifelse(data$ID == 2, 5,
ifelse(data$ID == 3, 10, "NA")))))
```

Returns:

```
   time ID dose
1     0  1    1
2   168  1    1
3   336  1    1
4   341  1   NA
5   503  1   NA
6   504  1    1
7   673  1   NA
8   839  1   NA
9   840  1    1
10    0  2    5
11   24  2   NA
12   48  2   NA
13  168  2    5
14    0  3   10
15   24  3   NA
16   48  3   NA
17  168  3   10
18  336  3   10
```

Comment: awesome !! Thank you @matt

Comment: @abc if this works for you, please accept if you don't mind!

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the following fake data set:

```
fake_data <- data.frame(Time = round(168 * sample(c(runif(10, 0, 10), sample(1:10, replace = TRUE)))),
                        ID   = sample(50, 20))
```

And the following fake functional relationship between `Dose` and `ID` when `Time` is a multiple of 168:

```
f <- function(x) 2 + 3 * x
```

Then, the new column `Dose` can be computed as so:

```
dplyr::mutate(fake_data, Dose = ifelse(Time %% 168 < 1, f(ID), NA))
```

Note that here we assume that the `Time` variable in an integer. If it were double, we would probably need to have a condition such as `Time %% 168 < 1e-10`.